# About Box In New Thread

Tags: vb.net

I'm using About Box To Display progressBar And Text While backGround Form is loading But During form load About Box hangs Up And doesn't Show progressbar ,So Is there any way to Display That About Box in New Thread Or process ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This One

```
Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread
    thread = New Thread(Sub()
                             Using form As New AboutBox1
                                 Application.Run(form)
                             End Using
                         End Sub)
    thread.Start()
```

Comment: But How To Update progressbar In that About Box ?

Answer (score 3):

Is this while the main form is loading?  If so, set your about box as the "splash screen" in Project --> Properties.  Read my article [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/A_3671-Updating-a-Splash-Screen-with-Loading-Progress-in-a-VB-Net-WinForms-Application.html) on how to properly update that splash screen with progress.